# Automatic generate record using different weeks from start date to end date

Tags: sql, for-loop, view

I would like to create a view that have 3 columns: `Item,Date,Qty`

these view get data from 2 tables:

1. Tabel A: contain all 3 columns

   ```
   Item      Date          Qty
   A    2013-12-20        1   
   A    2013-12-27        2  
   B    2013-12-20        3 
   B    2013-12-27        4
   ```
2. Table B: contain the start date and end date

   ```
   StartDate       EndDate
   2013-12-20      2014-12-26
   ```

The time interval of each segment between start date and end date is one week.

I need to insert rows into the view when there is no row in Table A in specific weeks
The result should look like this:

```
Item      Date          Qty
  A    2013-12-20        1   <-- Start Day
  A    2013-12-27        2   
  A    2014-1-3          0   <--mark qty as 0 when there is no record in Table A 
  A    2014-1-10         0   <--mark qty as 0 when there is no record in Table A
           .                 <--same logic til the end date
           .
  A    2014-12-26        0   <--End Date
  B    2013-12-20        3
  B    2013-12-27        4
  B    2014-1-3          0   <--mark qty as 0 when there is no record in Table A
  B    2014-1-10         0   <--mark qty as 0 when there is no record in Table A  
           .
           .
  B    2014-12-26        0   <--End Date
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...)? retag your question appropriately. SQL is just a Structured Query Language. What you're asking might use vendor specific features.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
    select
    b.StartDate,
    a.Item,
    isnull(sum(a.Qty),0) as Qty
    from
    TableB b left join
    TableA a on a.Date >= b.StartDate and a.Date <= b.EndDate
    group by a.Item, b.StartDate
```

These parts you may need to slightly change based on the RDBMS being used.

```
a.Date >= b.StartDate and a.Date <= b.EndDate
isnull(sum(a.Qty),0)
```

Comment: I assumed you need the data aggregated on a weekly basis (for the weeks defined in TableB).